# WooCommerce: in Shipping Options there is no option Free Shipping. Why?

Tags: woocommerce

[image: screenshot:no option Free Shipping]

WordPress WooCommerce:  in Shipping Options there is no option Free Shipping. Why?

Answer (score 1):

[image]You have to define a Shipping method in Shipping Zones. There you will see "Envio Gratuito", which in English translate as "Free Shipping".

Sorry but my Woocommerce is in spanish because of my client. But the options should be in the same place

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add shipping method for each your shipping your include FREE SHIPPING
[image]